# Generation of the symplectic by involutions

Tags: gr.group-theory, classical-groups, symplectic-group

Let $G$ be a group. An involution is an element $g\in G$ such that $g^2=1$.
Let $F$ be a field, $V$ an $F$-vector space and $b:V\times V \rightarrow F$ a nondegenerate alternating bilinear form. The set $\mathrm{Sp}(V,b)=\{ f:V\rightarrow V \mid f \mathrm{\ is\ bijective\ and\ } b(f(x),f(y))=b(x,y) \forall x,y \in V\}$ with the composition of maps is a group called the symplectic group of $(V,b)$. It is well-known that the symplectic group is generated by transvections. Is it also generated by involutions in $\mathrm{Sp}(V,b)$?

Comment: Is $b$ non-degenerate? What about $F=\mathbb{R}$, $V$ 1-dimensional, $b=0$?

Comment: Note that the projective symplectic group is simple (unless you're in some very special cases, see below). In this case (clearly having a non-trivial involution) it must be generated by involutions, as these generate a normal subgroup. See http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_symplectic_group_is_simple

Comment: Alternatively: use the fact that it is generated by $\text{SL}_2$'s.

Comment: May I ask you to be more specific?

Comment: Note that on a two dimensional space the form $(a,c),(b,d)\mapsto ad-bc$ is just the determinant, so $\text{Sp}=\text{SL}$. Thus also in higher dimensions the symplectic group contains many copies of $\text{SL}_2$. In fact, it is generated by these (this, again, could be seen by simplicity, but in fact it holds in a complete generality (I think)).

Comment: I am not sure. In $SL_2$ the only nontrivial symplectic involution is $-1$.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. $\text{PSL}_2$ is generated by involution, but $\text{SL}_2$ does not, I was too quick to answer...

Comment: So the answer should be: no in dim=2 (but yes for the projective group) and yes in higher dimensions.

Comment: Just to justify my comment above and finish the discussion: $\text{Sp}(4)$ does contain a copy of $\text{GL}_2$ embedded by $A\mapsto$ a block diagonal matrix with $A$ and the transpose inverse of $A$ on the 2x2 diagonal blocks. Here the form is given by $I$ and $-I$ on the of-diagonal blocks.

Comment: Note that if the field has characteristic $2$, then transvections are involutions so the answer is YES immediately (at least for finite fields -- I'm not sure about simplicity results for infinite fields).... In particular (with reference to the comments above) note that ${\rm SL}_2(2^a)$ is generated by involutions

Comment: @NickGill thanks for this correction. I put an answer based on it. Projective special linear and symplectic groups are always simple over infinite fields.

Comment: @UriBader, that's an interesting fact about infinite fields -- and one I should have known already! Thanks for filling in a gap in my knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an answer based on the many comments by myself and by Nick Gill.

In characteristic 2 the transvections are always involutions, so generation by transvections implies generation by involutions in all dimensions.
Below I will assume that the characteristic is not 2.

In dimensions 2 the determinant is a symplectic form, thus $G$ is conjugated to $\text{SL}_2(F)$. Then it is easy to check that the only involutions in $G$ are $1$ and $-1$. In particular, $G$ is not generated by involtions.
Below I will assume that the dimension is not 2.

I claim that $G$ is generated by involutions.
Note first that $G$ has at least one non-central involution:
for example one can view the form as a direct sum of lower dimensional ones, take 1 on one and -1 on the other. 
Note also that the group generated by all non-central involution is normal and not central. This group must be $G$, as every proper normal subgroup of $G$ is central. Indeed, this is the case for every symplectic group apart of $\text{Sp}(2,\mathbb{F}_2)$, $\text{Sp}(2,\mathbb{F}_3)$ and $\text{Sp}(4,\mathbb{F}_2)$, and by the assumptions above $G$ is not in this list.